# Transform a 3D objects to binary 3D matrix

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, image3d

Suppose that we have an unknown 3d object and we need to estimate it. We suppose that the object is inside a grid as below and we can do some test to eliminate the 
cubes or"voxel" which are not a part of the object. Finally we will get two parts of cubes: cubes that belong to the object (**A**) and cubes that does not belong to a 3d object **(B)**.
What I need is to construct a 3D binary  matrix where for each coordinates of cubes A, matrix take 1 and for each coordinates of cubes B, matrix take 0.

```
Table[{x,y,z},{x,1,100,3},{y,1,100,3},{z,1,100,3}]
```

I think, SparseArray can be a solution.

Comment: `SparseArray` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: what is lacking here is we have no idea what you mean by "part" or "object"

Comment: @george2079, I edited my question and I hope that it is very clear!

Comment: You need to do an insideness test on each point. Without knowing the form of your  "unknown object" its hard to provide more help.

Comment: If voxels are indexed by positive integer triples `{i,j,k}` and `ll` is the list of voxels indices in A, then it is just `SparseArray[ll->1]`.

Answer (score 4):

Your text doesn't really match your example. You start with the grid coordinates, so just create your array.

```
 Image3D[SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ Position[DiskMatrix[{12, 10, 8}], 1]]]
```

or just `Image3D[DiskMatrix[{12, 10, 8}]]`

[image]

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question